# Run SSIS Package with 2 Different Configurations

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

We have a SSIS job called ExportData and it accepts the 'ExportType' Parameter.  The ExportType parameter can be 'schedule' or 'unschedule'.

I created the Variable called '@ExportType' and created the SSIS Configuration and expose the variable in the Configuration file and called it 'ScheduleConfig'.  I copied that file and change the value to 'unschedule' and called it 'UnscheduleConfig'.

I created the SSIS Job in the SQL Server 2008 and set up 2 steps for both 'Schedule' and 'Unschedule'.  I attached the correct config file for each Step.  But whichever step I run, it always execute 'Schedule'.  I am sure and double checked the Config files and Steps.

How can I run 2 different jobs with 2 different configuration files?

I did try by using the SetValues method and it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly. here is a sample package created in `SSIS 2008 R2` and does what you are looking for. The sample uses a single package, which is executed under two different SQL agent job steps and both the steps use a different copies of the same configuration file. The configuration files hold different values for the variable used inside the package.

- Created a sample SSIS package named `SO_10177578`. Within the package, created a package variable named **`ExportType`** of data type `String`. Also, placed the `Execute SQL Task` on the Control Flow tab. This task will help to identify the value being passed to the variable `ExportType`.

[image: New package]

- Added the OLE DB connection to a sample database and named the connection as `SQLServer`. I chose to use SQL Server authentication for this connection manager.

[image: Connection manager]

- Within the SQL database, created a table named `dbo.ExportData` with the following strucutre. `Id` column is a identity column.

[image: Table structure]

- The table doesn't contain any data to begin with. This table will be populated with data when the package is executed.

[image: No data to begin with]

- On the SSIS package, clicked on the `SSIS` menu --> selected `Package Configuration` option. On the Package Configurations Organizer dialog, selected the *Enable package configurations* checkbox and clicked on the *Add* button. Created a new package configuration of the type `XML Configuration file`. Selected a path to store the file.

[image: Package type]

- Added the **Value** property of the variable `ExportType` and the **ConnectionString** property of the connection manager `SQLServer` to the configuration file.

[image: Values added to file]

- On the Execute SQL Task, selected the *Connection* to be `SQLServer` and set the *SQLStatement* property to **`INSERT INTO dbo.ExportData (PackageName, ExportTypeValue) VALUES (?, ?)`**

[image: Execute SQL Task General]

- Configured both the parameters to the appropriate variables available on the package. Now the package is ready for deployment.

[image: Parameter mapping]

- On the database server's SQL Agent node, created a new SQL job named `Test_ExportData`. `Owner` field information is removed to hide sensitive information.

[image: SQL job]

- On the SQL job's Steps page, created two steps named `Step_01` and `Step_02`.

[image: SQL Job steps]

- Step 1 is configured as below with the package being stored in the path `c:\temp\SO_10177578.dtsx`.

[image: Step 1 Package]

- Copied the package configuration file created using the package and changed the value for the variable `ExportType` to **Schedule**. Named the configuration file as `ScheduleConfig.dtsConfig`. Screenshot shows only part of the configuration file to hide sensitive connection string information.

[image: ScheduleConfig]

- In step 1 of the job, referred the newly created package configuration file from the path `c:\temp\Test\ScheduleConfig.dtsConfig.`

[image: Step 1 config]

- Step 2 is configured as below and it uses the same package stored in the path `c:\temp\SO_10177578.dtsx` as used by step 1.

[image: Step 2 Package]

- Copied the package configuration file created using the package and changed the value for the variable `ExportType` to **Unschedule**. Named the configuration file as `UnscheduleConfig.dtsConfig`. Screenshot shows only part of the configuration file to hide sensitive connection string information.

[image: UnscheduleConfig]

- In step 2 of the job, referred the newly created package configuration file from the path `c:\temp\Test\UnscheduleConfig.dtsConfig.`

[image: Step 2 Config]

- Now, both the steps are configured. Executed the new SQL agent job.

[image: Job executed]

- Queried the table `ExportData`. You can notice that the package was executed twice and each execution in the SQL agent job's steps used the appropriate configuration files specified on the steps.

[image: Data verified.]

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is exactly the way I have made yesterday.  It works first 3 or 4 tests, but no longer working after that.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you not store @ExportType in an SSIS Configuration. You can override the value from the DTEXEC command line by adding a SET switch similar to:

/SET "\Package.Variables[ExportType].Properties[Value]";Schedule

You can use the same PackagePath above to override this variable value in the SQL Agent Integration Services Job Step Type on the Set Values tab.

Hope this helps,
Andy

Answer (score 2):

you cant do that. The SSIS wont read the new configuration.

You need to call the package twice, one time with config file A and one time with config file B. On each config file you will have the @ExportType variable set to  'schedule' and 'unschedule'.

You can only set a parameter once. Even if you use DTEXEC with the /Config option for example you CANT overwrite a parameter that is already set